# Windows Workflow 4.5 Version Mapping

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

Suppose if there are two versions of the workflow, some instances are running on version1 and some on version2 , Is there any way so that we can call version1 workflow instead of version2 for a new instance, as we create a instance of workflow it will by default create the instance of version2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.net Framework 4.5 introduces Workflow Versioning which seems to be exactly what you need.

These two links should be enough to get started:

[Using WorkflowIdentity and Versioning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh305677%28VS.110%29.aspx)

[How to: Host Multiple Versions of a Workflow Side-by-Side](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj205425.aspx)

Comment: I am using WorkflowService (.xamlx) which internally provide versioning by using workflow identity, so the problem is when I implement versioning with workflow service it will call only the latest workflow version for the new instance ,but my requirement is to call the older version of workflow while I create a new instance

Comment: @KirankumarC WorkflowService versioning provide option to resume already started workflows with a older version, but new requests will be processed with the latest version. If you need to execute two versions of same workflow concurrently then you probably should look into this instead [Versioning long running Workflow Services in WF4, the code](http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2010/11/16/versioning-long-running-workflow-services-in-wf4-the-code.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Enes, that article might solve my problem if I have any question I will take your suggestion.