# Workflow foundation instances not found after dependent assemblies change version

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

We have a workflow with several activities in a strong-named assembly. While the workflow is waiting for a user action, we update the assembly to a newer version. On the next step execution, workflow foundation suddenly says that it can no longer find the workflow instance. This is literally about the assembly version number. If we don't change the version number, it keeps working. The exception additional information is:

**The execution of the InstancePersistenceCommand named {urn:schemas-microsoft-com:System.Activities.Persistence/command}LoadWorkflowByInstanceKey was interrupted by an error.**

The fault code name is **InstanceNotFound** .

Has anyone encountered something like this?

Comment: Haven't seen this error myself, but here's a link that describes how to log more detailed WF persistence info: https://pablocastilla.wordpress.com/2012/05/18/how-to-analyze-a-workflow-foundation-4-0-persistence-problem/ Heads up, the log is pretty verbose and grows large very quickly. So turn on, reproduce, turn off :)

Comment: This might help as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15703857/windows-workflow-4-5-version-mapping

Comment: What's your actual question? "Has anyone encountered something like this?" will yield "Yes" or "No"

Comment: The .exe.config might have an AssemblyRedirect entry. Similar issues in GAC are solved with a policy file.